# Setting up Doctrine Entity for pivot table

Tags: orm, doctrine-orm

I have a MySQL database that uses Doctrine 2 for ORM that I need to add my pivot table to. The database was set up by someone who is no longer around and has since been updated manually by several people so the MWB file doesn't match up anymore and I don't even know if it was used or how it would've been used.

Basically I have a Property entity which I have manually added more fields to and manually updated the Entity and a Feature entity which I have also manually set up and I need to set up the relationship between them (A Property can have many Features and a Feature can have many Propertys so that's Many To Many, right?)

I either need to get the automated way updated if there was one, or manually set up the pivot table.

Comment: There are more than 1 way to setup Doctrine2. Do you use annotation or  config file (i.e. yml or xml ) to specify the fields ?

Comment: I think it was done in MySQL Workbench then exported to annotation. There are no yml or xml files I can see in the project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I manually rebuilt the whole database in MySQL Workbench and exported the entities again.